# How to highlight multiple items given their positions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse [W3c API JSON](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Output-%C2%BB-JSON) output with javascript and I am stuck in how to place some spans inside some keywords, given their columns ( their position in the string )

I have re-organized the messages with PHP, so I have ended with something that reads with the following:

```
    $.each(data.messages,function(line,msgs) {
        content = $("#l"+line).text();
        offset = 0;

        $.each(msgs,function(i,v) {
            position = v.firstColumn+v.hiliteStart+offset;
            length = v.hiliteLength;

            if (isNaN(position)) {
                position = v.lastColumn+v.hiliteStart;
            }

            content = content.substr(0, position)+'[span]'+content.substr(position, length)+'[/span]'+content.substr(position + length);
            offset += 13; //offset compensates for [span] and [/span]
        });
        //htmlentites function from locutus.io
        nst = htmlentities(content);
        nst = nst.replace(/\[span\]/g,'<span>');
        nst = nst.replace(/\[\/span\]/g,'</span>');
        $("#l"+line).html(nst);

      });
```

My goal here is to highlight several errors and warnings within the same line of HTML code.

Comment: Did you tried [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)?

Comment: Yes I did, but it does not markup by line column ( or maybe I missed that part in the docs )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by defining your highlight ranges as an object, and work from there. For instance,

```
  ranges = [{
    "begin": 145,
    "end": 155
  }, {
    "begin": 4,
    "end": 18
  }, {
    "begin": 4,
    "end": 18
  }, {
    "begin": 90,
    "end": 102
  }, {
    "begin": 4,
    "end": 41
  }];
```

Whether these are defined within your js, or if they come from a server api is up to you and how you design your program. But once you have these defined, create a function that takes your original string, and this collection of ranges, and breaks up your string (preferrably using `slice`) into a collection of string segments. Then you can iterate through your segments and append `<span>` and `</span>` as necessary, and then place your final string into the DOM. I can't really tell from your code where you are getting your indexes from. But if you can put them in a clean structure like this, then you can cleanly break up your string.

One thing to keep in mind here is that you could have overlapping spans. And if that happens, you will need to flatten your ranges. Here is a set of functions that should get you what you need. Just call `createHighlightedString` with your text and your list of highlight ranges. It will flatten your ranges if necessary and give you a clean result. At the bottom of this there is a link to a working sample.

```
//Your implementation would look "something" like this
nst = htmlentities(content);
var ranges = [];//??? - GET YOUR RANGES DEFINED CLEANLY HERE
var highlightedString = createHighlightedString(ranges,nst);
$("#l"+line).html(highlightedString);

function createHighlightedString(ranges, text) {
  var flatRanges = flattenRanges(ranges);
  var inflatedRanges = inflateRanges(flatRanges, text.length);
  var filledRanges = fillRanges(inflatedRanges, text);
  var str = "";
  var index = 0;
  for (var i in filledRanges) {
    var range = filledRanges[i];
    var begin = range.begin, end = range.end;
    if (range.count > 0) {
      str += "<span class='highlight'>" + range.text + "</span>";
    } else {
      str += range.text;
    }
  }
  return str;
}

function flattenRanges(ranges) {
  var points = [];
  var flattened = [];
  for (var i in ranges) {
    if (ranges[i].end < ranges[i].begin) { //RE-ORDER THIS ITEM (BEGIN/END)
      var tmp = ranges[i].end+1; //RE-ORDER BY SWAPPING
      ranges[i].end = ranges[i].begin;
      ranges[i].begin = tmp;
    }
    points.push(ranges[i].begin);
    points.push(ranges[i].end);
  }
  //MAKE SURE OUR LIST OF POINTS IS IN ORDER
  points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
  //FIND THE INTERSECTING SPANS FOR EACH PAIR OF POINTS (IF ANY)
  //ALSO MERGE THE ATTRIBUTES OF EACH INTERSECTING SPAN, AND INCREASE THE COUNT FOR EACH INTERSECTION
  for (var i in points) {
    if (i==0 || points[i]==points[i-1]) continue;
    var includedRanges = ranges.filter(function(x){
      return (Math.max(x.begin,points[i-1]) < Math.min(x.end,points[i]));
    });
    if (includedRanges.length > 0) {
      var flattenedRange = {
        begin:points[i-1],
        end:points[i],
        count:0
      }
      for (var j in includedRanges) {
        var includedRange = includedRanges[j];
        for (var prop in includedRange) {
          if (prop != 'begin' && prop != 'end') {
            if (!flattenedRange[prop]) flattenedRange[prop] = [];
            flattenedRange[prop].push(includedRange[prop]);
          }
        }
        flattenedRange.count++;
      }
      flattened.push(flattenedRange);
    }
  }
  return flattened;
}

function inflateRanges(ranges, length=0) {
  var inflated = [];
  var lastIndex;
  for (var i in ranges) {
    if (i==0) {
      //IF THERE IS EMPTY TEXT IN THE BEGINNING, CREATE AN EMPTY RANGE
      if (ranges[i].begin > 0){
        inflated.push({
          begin:0,
          end:ranges[i].begin-1,
          count:0
        });
      }
      inflated.push(ranges[i]);
    } else {
      if (ranges[i].begin == ranges[i-1].end) {
        ranges[i-1].end--;
      }
      if (ranges[i].begin - ranges[i-1].end > 1) {
        inflated.push({
          begin:ranges[i-1].end+1,
          end:ranges[i].begin-1,
          count:0
        });
      }
      inflated.push(ranges[i]);
    }
    lastIndex = ranges[i].end;
  }
  //FOR SIMPLICITY, ADD ANY REMAINING TEXT AS AN EMPTY RANGE
  if (lastIndex+1 < length-1) {
    inflated.push({
      begin:lastIndex+1,
      end:length-1,
      count:0
    })
  }
  return inflated;
}

function fillRanges(ranges, text) {
  for (var i in ranges) {
    ranges[i].text = text.slice(ranges[i].begin,ranges[i].end+1);
  }
  return ranges;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/shfpxp82/10/

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I have encountered some issues with the span &quots; ( they count as characters if I htmlentities first ), but i'll use some BBCode to replace later on and it will be working like I intented. :D

Comment: Good to hear. Best of luck!